# JS button not displaying if `!read.book` is true

Tags: javascript, html

The Odin Project: Library project:
Currently stuck with getting a Book Read button to appear if the book has not been read.

This is the relevant bit of code:

```js
let myLibrary = [
  {
    title: "HardCode",
    author: "Sir Not Appearing",
    pages: "infinite",
    read: false,
  },
];

function book(title, author, pages, read) {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.pages = pages;
  this.read = read.toLowerCase() === "y";
  console.log("book-", this.info);
}

function addBookToLibrary() {
  const titleInput = document.getElementById("title");
  const authorInput = document.getElementById("author");
  const pagesInput = document.getElementById("pages");
  const readInput = document.getElementById("read");
  const title = titleInput.value;    
  const author = authorInput.value;   
  const pages = pagesInput.value;     
  const readValue = readInput.value;  

  if (title && author && pages && readValue) {
    const newBook = new book(title, author, pages, readValue);
    myLibrary.push(newBook);
    titleInput.value = "";            
    authorInput.value = "";           
    pagesInput.value = "";            
    readInput.value = "";            

    displayLibrary();
  }
}

function displayLibrary() {
  const existingLibraries = document.querySelectorAll("div.library");
  existingLibraries.forEach((existingLibrary) => {
    existingLibrary.remove();
  });

  const libraryContainer = document.createElement("div");
  libraryContainer.className = "library";
  libraryContainer.innerText = "Library";

  myLibrary.forEach((book, index) => {
    const bookDetails = document.createElement("div");

    const delBook = document.createElement("button");
    delBook.innerText = "Delete Book";
    // insert eventListener here for click
    if (!book.read) {
      const readBook = document.createElement("button");
      readBook.innerText = "Read Book";
      // insert addEventListener here
      bookDetails.appendChild(readBook);
    }

    bookDetails.textContent = `${book.title} by ${book.author}, ${
      book.pages} pages, ${book.read ? "this book is read." : "this book is unread."}`;
    bookDetails.appendChild(delBook);
    libraryContainer.appendChild(bookDetails);
  });

  document.body.appendChild(libraryContainer);
}
displayLibrary();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Book Library</title>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Book Library</h1>
    <div class="entry">
        <p>Enter the details of your book below:</p>
        <div>
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="title">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="author">Author</label>
            <input type="text" id="author">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="pages">Pages</label>
            <input type="text" id="pages">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="read">Read</label>
            <input type="text" id="read">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="addBookToLibrary()">Add Book</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The button should display only if the book has not been read.

Dev tools and console.log got the code to this point.
When it was coded to just show the button without a read rule it displayed along with the delete button as expected.  Once moved into the if code it ceased working.  No errors displayed.

Regards.

Comment: To add to what @Andy wrote, when you have a variable that can only have a binary value, it's best to store that as a Boolean with `true` or `false`.

Comment: @Andy I'm unclear on your meaning.  Is your response based on the fact that in myLibrary read: false and this.read is using ==='y' as opposed to modifying it to read true?
Or is there another reason for your comment?

Comment: Sorry @Loptr I misread your code. Ignore the first part but the second part is still valid.

Comment: The issue stems, I think, from the line starting with `bookDetails.textContent` which overwrites the "read" button that you add first. If you move that line _before_ the conditional it should work as expected @Loptr.